# Prolog Variable Name Starting Underscore then Capital

Tags: prolog

Give the following knowledge base:

```
cityinCountry(paris, france ) . /* Paris is a city in France*/
cityinCountry(berlin, germany).
cityinCountry(cairo, egypt).
cityinCountry(munich, germany).
```

Why does `cityinCountry(_City, germany).` return `True`, while `cityinCountry(City, germany).` returns `berlin; munich`?

The definition I was given for variable states that they are denoted by an identifier that starts with a capital letter or an underscore(_). Yet my two examples behave differently. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still a variable, but by using this name in a query you are telling Prolog (or at least your implementation of Prolog) that you don't want to show its value. E.g. `cityInCountry(_City, Country)` will print the expected four results, but only show the `Country` values.

Weirdly, I can't find explicit documentation of this, e.g. in http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=singleton. The only difference it gives is

> A singleton variable is a variable that appears only one time in a clause. It can always be replaced by _, the anonymous variable. In some cases, however, people prefer to give the variable a name. As mistyping a variable is a common mistake, Prolog systems generally give a warning (controlled by style_check/1) if a variable is used only once. The system can be informed that a variable is meant to appear once by starting it with an underscore, e.g., `_Name`.

The closest I can find is http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/dontcare.html:

> This indicates what the _ variable is actually representing, but has the feature that the binding of `_Anybody` typically doesn't get reported when Prolog finds a solution.

but there `_Anybody` is inside the body of a rule and wouldn't be reported in modern Prolog implementations anyway.

Comment: So does it behave just like the the anonymous variable `_`?

Comment: @Robin yes, but this is in whichever implementation of Prolog you are using. The latest SWI-Prolog: `?- cityinCountry(_City, germany). _City = berlin ; _City = munich.`, but GNU-Prolog: `| ?- cityinCountry(_, germany). true ? ; yes`.
So it depends.

Comment: Not quite: if you use this variable more than once, it follows the same rules as normal variables and not as `_`.